# Text field overlay with back-drop like Clear iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've been playing around with [JTGestureBasedTableView](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo), but this library only deals with pulling and swiping gesture handling.

I am trying to figure out how the overlay text field input (with translucent background) is implemented in Clear iPhone app (screenshot below). This is the point when you pull down a new cell and it turns into a text field, and once you finish typing in, the content gets filled into the top-most cell, which is presumably hidden behind the textfield.

What is the simplest way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an excellent tutorial on clear app by Colin Eberhardt](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13) .It explains well how the implementation is done